# copy issues on fork repo to original repo

Tags: github, github-issues

I want to see the issues I have made on forked repo on the original repo.

I did some experiment: I made some issues on my fork repo and was trying to see them on my original repo by merging through pull & request.

However, all I did was just merging a file only.
**I was not able to see the issues on the original repo**.

I was trying to do some research about it but hard to get some info related to the issues on the forked repo.

How can I add the issues I have made from forked repo to the main (original) repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can [transfer an issue from one repository to the other](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/tracking-your-work-with-issues/transferring-an-issue-to-another-repository)

And you can automate the process using the GitHuh CLI command [`gh issue transfer`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_transfer)

However that means those issues are *moved*, no longer visible on their original fork repository.

Duplicating them or seeing them from the main repository is [asked since July 2021](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/4480), but not yet implemented.